# Drupal Media Library - File Upload Library shows "No files available."

Tags: drupal, upload, media

I am actualy running in some sort of strange problem. I installed Media 7.x-2.x-alpha2. I can upload files without any problems. When I go to "admin/content/file" I see the uploaded files.

[image]

Now comes the problem, when I want to add a image via the library dialog, while creating a new node, the box shows me "No files available.".

[image]

I checked the media browser view and the very strange is, that the files shows up in there

[image]

I tried updating to newest dev release and checked the permissions, but anything looks just fine. I am working as user 1.

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem could be solved by removing the Query Tag under "Query settings" inside the view options.
I have no idea why, but after removing it, anything works just fine.

Comment: is this a drupal update problem? the fix worked for me too but I don't know why I had this problem in the first place. Any ideas ?